# Array Level insertion in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am having task in php,(i.e.) having two array the first level array key contain its insert id .so the second level array values  wants to be insert in table.

the problem is i should  use one foreach only because of code optimization,the answer i want  to insert the second level array in table with first level array value (id) which is an parent category for the second level array.

so i want to insert correspond id with second level array value.the array is given below:

**first level array has value as id and key as category type**

```
     Array(
               [catws] => 2127
               [bar] => 2128
               [try] => 2129
               [tewt] => 2130
               [some] => 2131
                [cat] => 2132
             )
```

**second level array has key as firstlevel key**

```
    Array (
          [subcat] => Array
                 (
    > >                 [catws] => Array
    > >                     (
    > >                         [0] => PACKING 
    > >                     )
    > >     
    > >                 [bar] => Array
    > >                     (
    > >                         [0] => horse
    > >                         [1] => horse COIN
    > >                         [2] => horse  ARTICLE
    > >                         [3] => horse GIFT ITEM 
    > >                         [4] => horse SILVER
    > >                         [5] => horse PENDENT
    > >                         [6] => horse IDOLS
    > >                         [7] => horse ITEM PIECE PRICE
    > >                         [8] => horse PHOTO
    > >                         [9] => horse RING
    > >                         [10] => horse PRECIOUS RING
    > >                     )
    > >     
    > >                 [try] => Array
    > >                     (
    > >                        [0] => horse
    > >                         [1] => horse COINed
    > >                         [2] => horse  ARTICLEed
    > >                         [3] => horse GIFT ITEMed
    > >                         [4] => horse SILVERed
    > >                         [5] => horse PENDENTed
    > >                         [6] => horse IDOLSed
    > >                         [7] => horse ITEMed
    > >                         [9] => horse RINGed
    > >                         [10] => PRECIOUS horse
    > >                     )
    > >     
    > >                 [tewt] => Array
    > >                     (
    > >                      [0] => tewt
    > >                         [1] => tewt COINsese
    > >                         [2] => tewt  ARTICLEed
    > >                         [3] => tewt GIFT ITEMed
    > >                         [4] => tewt SILVERed
    > >                         [5] => tewt PENDENTed
    > >                         [6] => tewt IDOLSed
    > >                         [7] => tewt ITEMed
    > >                         [9] => tewt RINGed
    > >                         [10] => tewt horse
    > >                     )
    > >     
    > >                 [some] => Array
    > >                     (
    > >                         [1] => some COINsese
    > >                         [2] => some  ARTICLEed
    > >                         [3] => some tewt GIFT ITEMed
    > >                         [4] => some  SILVERed
    > >                         [5] => some PENDENTed
    > >                         [6] => some IDOLSed
    > >                         [7] => some ITEMed
    > >                         [9] => some RINGed
    > >                         [10] => some horse
    > >                       
    > >                     )
    > >     
    > >                 [cat] => Array
    > >                     (
    > >                         [1] => cat COINsese
    > >                         [2] => cat  ARTICLEed
    > >                         [3] => cat tewt GIFT ITEMed
    > >                         [4] => cat  SILVERed
    > >                         [5] => cat PENDENTed
    > >                         [6] => cat IDOLSed
    > >                         [7] => cat ITEMed
    > >                         [9] => cat RINGed
    > >                         [10] => cat horse
    > >                     )
    > >     
    > >             )
    > >     
    > >     )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume

- your first array is `$categories = array('catws' => 2127, ...)` and
- your second array is `$items = array('catws' => array(0 => 'PACKING'), 'bar' => ...)`
  (in your example this is the second dimension of the array)
- your table layout is s.th. like `category (int) | id (int) | name (string/varchar)`

then you would iterate over your items to generate either a part of a query string (one row) or generate another array to pass it to a MySQL wrapper that takes an array to somehow build the insert query itself:

```
foreach($items as $catname => $cat) {
    if(!array_key_exists($catname, $categories)) {
        continue; // skip unknown categories
    }
    $catid = $categories[$catname];

    foreach($cat as $itemid => $item) {
        // generate row triple
        $rows[] = sprintf('(%d, %d, %s)', $catid, $itemid, $item);
        // OR generate array for a wrapper
        $rows[] = array(
            'category' => $catid,
            'id' => $itemid,
            'name' => $item
        );
    }
}
```

NOTE that you **have to** use nested loops because you have a nested array.

---

When you generate the row triples, you could create a query like this:

```
$query = sprintf(
    'INSERT INTO `tablename` (category, id, name) VALUES %s',
    implode(',', $rows)
);
```

**ALSO NOTE** that in this code example, no value escaping is done as this depends on your MySQL implementation.
One safe solution would be to use a wrapper that takes an array (second `$rows[]` example) and performs internal sanitizing or - even better - use prepared statements.